# how to combine the logical operator NOT together with the orientation media feature

Tags: css, orientation, media-queries, logical-operators

I need to target css properties to any device which is NOT iPad and based on the device orientation.

Nested media queries don't work on my simulator. Example

```
@media not screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) {

    @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
        DIV { border: solid 1px yellow; }
    }

    @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
        DIV { border: solid 1px red; }
    }
}
```

the previous always gives yellow borders on both orientation.
Honestly I never used them as I read they might not work as expected on many devices.

I cannot find a way to split it onto separated combined queries, such as

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) and not screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) {
    DIV { border: solid 1px yellow; }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) and not screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) {
    DIV { border: solid 1px red; }
}
```

this never matches.

I know the comma separated queries are logical OR, but I also tried

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait), not screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) {
    DIV { border: solid 1px yellow; }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape), not screen and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) {
    DIV { border: solid 1px red; }
}
```

and this obviously produces always red borders.

I know I can overwrite css properties but my question is how to correctly use the logical NOT operator combined with orientation as I'm not very familiar in using this operator and I want to learn how to use it properly and do some test over different devices.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience in identifying iPad, iPhone and such to apply specific layout tweaks to a site i am quite happy to say these hints here did the trick for me. http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/03/css-for-iphone-ipad-and-retina-displays/

Since you'd like to apply to every screen-media that's NOT possibly an iPad you can limit to min-device-width. I'm ignoring the Retina here as i could not find what device-width they'll report. So in your case i'd modify the iPad section from the code I linked to like this:

```
/* NOT iPad and Portrait */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 769px) and (orientation:portrait) {
}

/* NOT iPad and Landscape */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 769px) and (orientation:landscape) {
}
```

Hope I could help you.